# Tournament Program

Tags: python, list, tournament

we are required to create a program that sets up the first round of a tournament for a project.  If there is an uneven amount of contestants, the program is required to add a bye.  Here is my code:

```
from random import*
bye=[]
teams=[]
while True:
    team=str(input("Enter the team names.(-1 to exit):\n"))
    teams.append(team)
    if team=="-1": break

if (len(teams))%2!=0:
    teams.append("bye")
print("          Tournament         ")
print("------------------------------")

shuffle(teams)
for i in range(len(teams)):
    print(team[i], team[i+1])
```

Errors?

Comment: "Errors?" Why don't you run it yourself and see? That's why you have a python interpreter. Also please don't tag this `java` if it isn't java.,

Comment: I have ran it and I have gotten the error string index out of range.  I can't seem to find the error in it as I am a high school student currently learning the basics of python and programming.

Comment: you can check a plugin I have made, it has all the logic you are looking for: https://github.com/xoco70/laravel-tournaments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have comes up in your method of printing out the results:

```
for i in range(len(teams)):
    print(team[i],team[i+1])
```

First of all, you have `team` instead of `teams` in the print statement, which is actually the string where you were storing user input, and should be `'-1'` by the time you're printing scores. You're getting the `string index out of range` error because it's trying to index the `team` string to the length of the `teams` list, which is likely larger than two.

Additionally, you're going to run into a similar problem with `teams[i+1]` since on the last iteration it will try and access one position beyond the length of the array. You're also going to be printing teams multiple times with how you have your loop set up, but I'll leave that to you to figure out.